# Set default kwargs when overrriding in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I have a class in Python that I want to instantiate with kwargs: e.g.

```
a = ClassA(happy=True)
```

I want to override this class with ClassB and set happy to True, I assumed this definition would work:

```
class ClassB(ClassA(happy=True))
```

However I get:

```
TypeError: 'ClassA' object is not callable
```

The workaround I have currently is to define ClassB as:

```
class ClassB(ClassA)
```

But then every time I instantiate ClassB, I have to do this:

```
b = ClassB(happy=True)
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: why not add `self.happy=True` in the constructor method `__init__` of classB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, happy=True):
        super().__init__(happy=happy)
```

When defining base classes of a class, that is all you do - define the base classes (here: `(ClassA)`).

What happens when you want create an instance of your class (e.g. `ClassB()`) is that its constructor (`__init__`) is called.

The base class apparently has a constructor which takes `False` as the default value, so you override the constructor and change its default argument value.

Then, call the base constructor with whatever the value is (`super().__init__(happy=happy)`).